# How to display an image grid in ResearchKit

Tags: swift, researchkit

For a question I am implementing  I have 16 images that I would like to present in a 4 x 4 grid.

The [documentation](http://researchkit.org/docs/Classes/ORKImageChoice.html) for ORKImageChoice indicates that "typically, image choices are displayed in a horizontal row" , but I don't want that.  How can I layout the images in a grid?

Here is my code thats is displaying the images inline:

```
    let pamTuples = [  
        (UIImage(named: "1_1")!, "1"),  
        (UIImage(named: "1_2")!, "2"),  
        (UIImage(named: "1_3")!, "3"),  
        (UIImage(named: "1_4")!, "4"),  
        (UIImage(named: "2_1")!, "5"),  
        (UIImage(named: "2_2")!, "6"),
        (UIImage(named: "2_3")!, "7"),
        (UIImage(named: "2_4")!, "8"),
        (UIImage(named: "3_1")!, "9"),
        (UIImage(named: "3_2")!, "10"),
        (UIImage(named: "3_3")!, "11"),
        (UIImage(named: "3_4")!, "12"),
        (UIImage(named: "4_1")!, "13"),
        (UIImage(named: "4_2")!, "14"),
        (UIImage(named: "4_3")!, "15"),
        (UIImage(named: "4_4")!, "16")    
    ]  

    let imageChoices : [ORKImageChoice] = pamTuples.map {  
        return ORKImageChoice(normalImage: $0.0, selectedImage: nil, text: $0.1, value: $0.1)  
    }  

    let pamAnswerFormat: ORKImageChoiceAnswerFormat = ORKAnswerFormat.choiceAnswerFormatWithImageChoices(imageChoices)  

    let pamQuestionStep = ORKQuestionStep(identifier: "mood image", title: pamQuestionStepTitle, answer: pamAnswerFormat)
```

Comment: Currently image choices can only be displayed in a horizontal row.

Answer (score 0):

*Cross-posting from [ResearchKit's GitHub Issue Tracker](https://github.com/ResearchKit/ResearchKit/issues/624).*

The *image choice answer format* doesn't currently provide support for this. You'd need to do a somewhat involved modification of the internals to support for this (you'd beed a way to specify how many columns/rows the grid would need, etc.)

A workaround I can think of using current RK capabilities, is using a form to display several individual *image choice answer format* on the same form, one for each row of your grid. See the *Mini Form* example in `ORKTest` for some sample code on how to include *image choice questions* in a form.